# Spy with extended WM_CHAR messages

Tags: windows, windows-messages, spy

Some years back I was able to easily catch with Spy++ to detect any keyboard presses that were sent to a window.

Now with spyxx_amd64.exe, the output looks differently:
[image]

I'm missing the parameters like which keycode was sent. 
All the sweet little details are missing.

Can anybody tell me what I need to do to show these extended parameters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
In the options menu I need to enable the following options:

[image]